# calculate the months between two dates

Tags: python, odoo

I need to calculate the months between two dates. I know it can be easy but I have a code and I can not complete it.

```
start_date=fields.Date(string="Startdate", requiered=True)

end_date=fields.Date(string="End_date", requiered=True)

duration=fields.Char(string="Duration", computer="_duration")

@api.multi 

@api.depends('start_date','end_date')

def _duration(self):

          if self.start_date and self.end_date:

               start_dt = fields.Datetime.from_string(self.start_date)

               finish_dt = fields.Datetime.from_string(self.end_date)

               difference = relativedelta(finish_dt, start_dt)

               month = difference.month
```

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to ask question in Stackoverflow. What problem you encountered specifically with your code?

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code

```
from datetime import datetime


def diff_month(d1, d2):
return (d1.year - d2.year) * 12 + d1.month - d2.month
```

or

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta

def get_months(d1, d2):
  date1 = datetime.strptime(str(d1), '%Y-%m-%d')
  date2 = datetime.strptime(str(d2), '%Y-%m-%d')
  print (date2, date1)
  r = relativedelta.relativedelta(date2, date1)
  months = r.months +  12 * r.years
  if r.days > 0:
    months += 1
  return  months


  month = get_months('2018-08-13','2019-06-30')
  print(month)
```

Comment: It does not work, I want the difference to appear after subtracting the months. For example 01/07/2019 - 01/03/2019 = 4 months

Comment: @AZCHILENO try it with  my first method

Comment: @AZCHILENO with your example both method appears to be right

Comment: I have to put @ api.multi

@ api.depends ('start_date', 'end_date') before def ....?

Comment: If you put @api.depends the function will be called depending on the date field. if the function depending up on date field you can add either @ api.depends or use onchange function also

Comment: @ api.multi @ api.depends ('start_date', 'end_date') def diff_month(d1, d2):
return (d1.year - d2.year) * 12 + d1.month - d2.month

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta
date1 = datetime.strptime(str('2019-03-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
date2 = datetime.strptime(str('2019-07-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
r = relativedelta.relativedelta(date2, date1)
print(r.months)
```

Comment: I have to put @ api.multi

@ api.depends ('start_date', 'end_date') before def date1...?

Comment: Yes, if you need the duration to change according to the dates

Comment: @api.multi 

@api.depends('start_date','end_date') date1 = datetime.strptime(str('2019-03-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
date2 = datetime.strptime(str('2019-07-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
r = relativedelta.relativedelta(date2, date1)
print(r.months)